# How does Enviorment GetFolderPath work when called from wcfservice that is hosted on webhotel

Tags: c#

I was thinking how does the Enviorment.GetFolderPath work if, it is called from a webservice that is hosted on a webhotel. 
Is the Enviorment then, the server that, the wcfservice is running on, or is the enviorment on the local computer/client that calls the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Enviorment is the server where the wcfservice is running on because the application is maybe called by an other application but the server where the code is executed is still the same.

Here is the documentation : [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can process a simple operation to be sure about where your code is executed, like the following :

```
Console.WriteLine("MachineName: {0}", Environment.MachineName);
Console.WriteLine("OSVersion: {0}", Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}",Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
```

You can find a lot of test to execute at the end of my link.

Comment: Short and simple. Thanks

Comment: Wait i'll try to find documentation.

Comment: Done. Don't forget to validate the answer ! :)